# Securing a service's secret

Tags: oracle

I have a TABLE sec.sec_secret_tab in the SEC schema

| OWNER | SERVICE_NAME | SECRET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ALPHA | service_1 | A1 |
| ALPHA | service_2 | A2 |
| BETA | service_1 | B1 |
| BETA | service_2 | B2 |

and this function:

```
FUNCTION sec.sec_get_secret (p_service_name VARCHAR2) 
IS
  vc_onwer VARCHAR2(32767); 
  vc_secret VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  vc_onwer := sec.mystery_func;

  SELECT secret
    INTO vc_secret
    FROM sec.sec_secret_tab
   WHERE service_name = p_service_name
     AND onwer = vc_onwer;

  RETURN vc_secret;

END sec_get_secret;
```

In the schema alpha, there is this procedure:

```
PROCEDURE alpha.show 
IS
  vc_secret VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  vc_secret := sec.sec_get_secret('service_1');

  dbms_output.put_line(vc_secret);

  vc_secret := sec.sec_get_secret('service_2');

  dbms_output.put_line(vc_secret);

END show;
```

In the schema beta, there is this procedure:

```
PROCEDURE beta.show 
IS
  vc_secret VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  vc_secret := sec.sec_get_secret('service_1');

  dbms_output.put_line(vc_secret);

  vc_secret := sec.sec_get_secret('service_2');

  dbms_output.put_line(vc_secret);

END show;
```

Knowing that

- the alpha and beta schemas have EXECUTE right on sec.sec_get_secret
- the user connected (lets call him OMEGA) has the EXECUTE rights on alpha.show and beta.show

How can I make the function sec.mystery_func to get the following output:

- if OMEGA calls alpha.show, 'A1' and 'A2' are displayed
- if OMEGA calls beta.show, 'B1' and 'B2' are displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `UTL_CALL_STACK` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_CALL_STACK.html), specifically [the `OWNER` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_CALL_STACK.html#GUID-39A71B1D-A39C-45F3-829A-20807FB64CF2):

> This function returns the owner name of the unit of the subprogram at the specified dynamic depth.

You want the owner of the calling package, so that's level 2:

```
vc_onwer := utl_call_stack.owner(2);
```

That package is available from Oracle 12cR1.